# UPDATING all fields from results of MAX of result of groups of results

Tags: mysql, max, dateadd

I have a table of grape patches. Each patch has a table of Sprays, which have a date & spray type, each table of spray types have a 'minimum time' til you can pick.

Patch table:

```
PatchID | earliestDate
1         ---
2         ---
```

Spray Table

```
SprayID | PatchID | TypeID  |Date
1         1         1        2019-06-1
2         1         2        2019-06-16
1         2         1        2019-06-16
2         2         2        2019-06-1
```

Spray Type

```
TypeID | minimumTime
1        14
2        28
```

I've grabbed out the

```
MAX(newEarliest) FROM ( SELECT DATE_ADD(Spray.Date, INTERVAL Type.minimumTime DAY) As newEarliest
FROM Spray
LEFT JOIN Patch ON Patch.PatchID = Spray.PatchID
LEFT JOIN Type ON Type.TypeID = Spray.TypeID) WHERE Patch.PatchID = 1;
```

But from here I'm stuck

```
UPDATE Patch SET EarliestDate = MAX(newEarliest) FROM ( SELECT DATE_ADD(Spray.Date, INTERVAL Type.minimumTime DAY) As newEarliest
FROM Spray
LEFT JOIN Patch ON Patch.PatchID = Spray.PatchID
LEFT JOIN Type ON Type.TypeID = Spray.TypeID) ) WHERE ??;
```

The Expected results should be, Patch 1 gets 14th of July, Patch 2 gets 30th of July.. yet I can't make that last connection. I'm hoping/expecting? I've just hit a wall and will need a breather, but maybe there is a SQL command that I've missed?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry, I thought I had?

Answer (score 1):

try this query. you can get the `max()` `group by` `PatchID` first as `subquery` before doing the update.

```
update Patch p    
Inner join (
    select t1.PatchID, max(date_add(t1.Date, interval t3.minimumTime day)) as newEarliest
    from Spray t1
    left join Patch t2 on t2.PatchID = t1.PatchID
    left join Type t3 on t3.TypeID = t1.TypeID
    group by t1.PatchID) t on t.PatchID = p.PatchID
set p.EarliestDate = t.newEarliest
```

Comment: I've tried this and several Variants, yet I get the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from ( SELECT t1.PatchID, '

Comment: @BaneStar007, try now